ChaCha20 counter implementation for QUIC packet protection in Rust
I am stuck trying to implement correctly the QUIC header protection using Rust.
The RFC says  to extract two variables, nonce and counter. But looking at all the libraries available out there, I can't find a suitable match to fulfil the requisites.
use chacha20::ChaCha20;
use chacha20::cipher::{KeyIvInit, StreamCipher};

//...

let mut cipher = ChaCha20::new(key, nonce);

let mut plaintext = data.to_vec();

cipher.apply_keystream(&mut plaintext);

If we pass along a 16 bytes nonce, it fails. Well it is expected as a nonce should be 12 bytes long.
But other Python for example allows it. I am confused on how to achieve the same result.
Can someone detail me a solution to implement the "counter" part using a reliable crate such as chacha20?

Can you say which Python's ChaCha20 you are referring to?

The RFC says you should have a 12 bytes nonce, so what is the problem?

Of course, that one https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/368e3505d583a358c4c52f43d19ed861493a8e5d/docs/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption.rst#L130

The problem is that we ignore the "counter" part, I don't know how to use it along with the rust ChaCha20

We cannot. I will dig into the C OpenSSL algorithm to find the algorithm behind it. It produce different output, and QUIC server rejected my payloads.

Try calling cipher.seek(your_u32_counter).
